# Display Twitter tag cloud in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter, tags, cloud

Is there a way to display a tag cloud of terms from a single Twitter account within Wordpress i.e. on a page or in the sidebar? I know there's a Delicious Wordpress sidebar tag-cloud - so figured there might be.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of [Twitter plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=twitter) at Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks. I've explored the plugin options, but none seem to do what I want.